# Transfering records with foreign key referring to new value

Tags: sqlite

In an SQLite DB, I have to transfer some records from two tables (`old_warnings` and `old_acknowledges`) to other two tables(`new_warnings` and `new_acknowledges`).

Transfering `warnings` is not a problem.

```
INSERT INTO new_warnings (event, comment, value)
SELECT event, comment, value
FROM old_warnings
WHERE old_warnings.event = 'one';
```

However, the `acknowledges` tables have the reference to the `warning` (warning_id:integer) it refers to and if I transfer the `acknowledges` first, I end up having the old `warning_id` in the table. But, if I transfer the `warnings` first, I don't have any reference to the new `id` to insert in the `new_acknowledges` table.

Any idea of how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

There could be few approaches you can take to achieve this... based onhow big is the data set.

1. Use of cursors
   Using cursor you can insert each row is new warning table capture the new_warningid created for that row and use it to insert respective Acknowledges referring to old_warning id and replacing with new_warningid.
2. use of temporary column in New_warning table which will hold old_warningid for lookup.
   Add a column "old_warningid" to new_warnings table and use that column as lookup while inserting rows in new_acknowldges tables to get corresponding "new_warningid".once the migration is complete you can drop the columns from new_warnings table.

Comment: I need to transfer about 100 warnings and, the acknowledges can't be more than that. Thanks